# How to extract text under "About us" for web pages using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, xml, beautifulsoup

I am new to webscraping and I am not sure how to extract text under "*About us*" from webpage.

Classes are different for "*About us*" header in different webpages.

Could you please guide me or provide code to extract text under "About us" in webpage like https://www.thestylistgroup.com/

I can see "*About us*" in headers but unable to extract data with this headers.

```
for heading in soup.find_all(re.compile("^h[1-6]")):

    print(heading.name + ' ' + heading.text.strip())
```

Thanks,
Naidu

Answer (score 0):

This script will select all `<Hx>` tags, which contains the string "About Us":

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.thestylistgroup.com/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all(lambda t: re.findall(r'h\d+', t.name) and t.text.strip().lower()=='about us'):
    print(tag)
    print(tag.next_sibling.text) # This will get text from the next sibling tag
```

Prints:

```
<h2 class="css-6r2li">About Us</h2>
The Stylist Group is a leading digital publisher and media platform with pioneering brands Stylist and Emerald Street. Within an inspiring, fast-paced, entrepreneurial environment we create original magazines and digital brands for Stylist Women - our successful, sophisticated, dynamic and urban audience. These people have very little time, a considerable disposable income and no patience with inauthentic attempts to try to engage them. Our purpose is to create content Stylist Women are proud to enjoy.
```

Comment: Dear Andrej, Thanks alot for your reply and resolved my issue.

Comment: For one of the webpage, content for "About company" is in same path as header, not as sibling.
Need to traverse to parent class but should not hard code class value.
URL : https://www.britishcornershop.co.uk/about-us
Need to fetch data under  "About British Corner Shop"

Comment: @Naidu Every webpage is different, there's no universal program that will scrape all pages 100%. It's necessary to modify scraper for each page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is always an immediate sibling you could use the following (bs4 4.7.1 +). Note that there is potential for incorrect results due to immediate sibling assumption.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.thestylistgroup.com/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
for h in range(1,7):
    header_with_sibling = soup.select('h' + str(h) + ':contains("About Us") + *')
    if header_with_sibling:
        for i in header_with_sibling:
            print(i.text)
```

---

If you want to stop at first match

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.thestylistgroup.com/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
for h in range(1,7):
    header_with_sibling = soup.select_one('h' + str(h) + ':contains("About Us") + *')
    if header_with_sibling:
        print(header_with_sibling.text)
        break
```

Comment: Dear QHarr, Thanks for your reply.FYI - getting error message: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for line 7

Comment: Copy paste the code exactly as is. They should both run fine as it is only a number to string conversion.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
For one of the webpage, content for "About company" is in same path as header, not as sibling. Need to traverse to parent class but should not hard code class value. URL : britishcornershop.co.uk/
Need to fetch data under "About British Corner Shop"

Comment: It won't work because there is there isn't a header of interest containing _About Us_ ... yes you could just use _About_ and then find parent but you are using a different relationship to then get the text you want. It is highly unlikely you can write a script which will work for all cases. You usually have a better chance with pages designed by the same person/company - but even then that's no guarantee.